# Blue transparent piece

Tags: part-identification

[image: blue piece]

Which piece is this? Seems space related.

Answer (score 4):

On bricklink, that's called [Trans-Light Blue Windscreen 5 x 2 x 1 2/3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6070#T=C&C=15) with design number 6070 and item numbers 607042 or 6153478.

[image]

Comment: What sets does it appear in that color, out of curiosity?

Comment: @nick012000 - Just click the BrickLink link! All the info is there. Here, a shortcut for you, it says there are 12 sets with this piece in this colour: https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6070&in=S

Comment: @Vilx- The Bricklink link didn't seen to be working fore on mobile, since it went all greyed out and unresponsive, but on a second look, it seems like the issue was a cookie permission popup that appeared outside the field of view of my phone screen.

Comment: @nick012000 - Ahh, yes. Been there, done that! Glad you could figure it out. :)